# FTP server functionality in Ruby/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to be able to receive ftp files from users from a desktop app and was wondering if there could be a way for Rails to process these requests despite being based on HTTP.

Comment: At this point. I have not found a gem for this. I will probably have to go with a separate ftp process.

Answer (score 2):

Typically you'd have your hosting machine handle the requests using a FTP-daemon.

If you have a reasonably large number of users sending files via FTP, you don't want to waste Rails' CPU time processing them.

Also, consider the security and administration issues. You'll have to write your own implementation in Rails. Using a built-in FTPd will allow you to piggyback on that.

Don't reinvent a wheel, reuse one that's well tested.

Comment: Good call on the server/admin issues. I guess I will have to poll the incoming files periodically. With an Http Post I could simply attach a method to the user's action (uploading the file)

Comment: @JacksonHenley Do you have control over the desktop app? If so, it could send an HTTP post to your Rails app just like a browser would.

Comment: @Nathan I have control over the app's code, which is written in MQL (Metatrader). However, getting HTTP working requires external .dlls and there isn't any easy solution by far (been down that road) whereas ftp is built in.